# Why reserving space with std::vector runs slower?

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

I created the following function: given a m * n matrix of ones and zeros, it return how many square submatrices have all ones

For example

```
Input: matrix =
[
  [0,1,1,1],
  [1,1,1,1],
  [0,1,1,1]
]

Output: 15
```

Explanation:
There are 10 squares of side 1.
There are 4 squares of side 2.
There is  1 square of side 3.

There is the program without reserving space.

```
int countSquares(vector<vector<int>>& matrix)
{
    const size_t rows{ matrix.size() }, cols{ matrix[0].size() }; //Get the number of rows and colums
    
    //Creating a dynamic programing matrix
    vector<vector<int>> dp(rows, vector<int>(cols)); //Initializing m * n elements (this should be slower than reserving without initializing)
    dp[0][0] = matrix[0][0];
    
    size_t count = dp[0][0]; //counter of the squares
    
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < rows; ++i) 
        count += dp[i][0] = matrix[i][0]; //Count squares in the first row and update the dynamic programming first row
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < cols; ++i)
        count += dp[0][i] = matrix[0][i]; //Count squares in the first colums and update the dynamic programming first column
    
    
    //Count the rest of squares and update the dynamic programming matrix
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < rows; ++i)
        for (size_t j{ 1 }; j < cols; ++j)
            count += dp[i][j] = matrix[i][j] ? min({ dp[i - 1][j], dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i][j - 1] }) + 1 : 0;
    
    return count;
}
```

This is exactly the same program but without initialization the dynamic programming matrix at construction and reserving all space before use

```
int countSquares(vector<vector<int>>& matrix)
{
    const size_t rows{ matrix.size() }, cols{ matrix[0].size() }; //Get the number of rows and colums

    //Creating a dynamic programing matrix
    vector<vector<int>> dp; //This time without default initialization
    dp.reserve(rows); 

    dp.push_back(vector<int>());
    dp.back().reserve(cols);
    dp.back().push_back(matrix[0][0]);

    size_t count = dp[0][0];

     //Count squares in the first row and update the dynamic programming first row
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        dp.push_back(vector<int>());
        dp.back().reserve(cols);
        dp.back().push_back(matrix[i][0]);
        count += dp.back().back();
    }

    //Count squares in the first colums and update the dynamic programming first column
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < cols; ++i)
    {
        dp[0].push_back(matrix[0][i]);
        count += dp[0].back();
    }   

    //Count the rest of squares and update the dynamic programming matrix
    for (size_t i{ 1 }; i < rows; ++i)
        for (size_t j{ 1 }; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            dp[i].push_back(matrix[i][j] ? min({ dp[i - 1][j], dp[i - 1][j - 1], dp[i][j - 1] }) + 1 : 0);
            count += dp[i].back();
        }

    return count;
}
```

Why the first option runs 50% faster ??

Update 1: I timed my functions with std::chrono::system_clock::now() in visual studio (creating a really long matrix) and also using this page :
https://leetcode.com/problems/count-square-submatrices-with-all-ones/
the first option runs at 90% and the second one at 40%

Comment: Probably because it does less work overall? `reserve` and `push_back` are not free; they need to do some internal bookkeeping.

Comment: How did you time your functions that you know that the first is 50% faster?

Comment: What optimization level did you set when compiling?

Comment: Thanks for replies. Updated my question with the time methods I used

Comment: Variables defined on stack are also initialized, so in second example variable is initialized with default values and then reallocation occurs. That is why it is slower.

Comment: @PabloArkadiusz Yes but how exactly did you time it? Did you run the functions once and get the time, or did you run them repeatedly and take the average?

Comment: @Nikola Im not sure. The second example creates an empty vector, then allocates space (without constructing nothing), and then initializing the allocated space only once. Where the reallocation occurs ?

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Yeah, tried multiple times, didn't take average time but the second example always runs slower (always tried both with same inputs)

Comment: @PabloArkadiusz `vector<vector<int>> dp;` initializes vector with default size, i think it is 8. So in the next size when you call `dp.reserve(rows); ` it reallocates memory to fit `rows` number of data. Same happens when you fill row data: 
`dp.push_back(vector<int>());
    dp.back().reserve(cols);`